# Hide Inline form in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, inline

My Django ModelAdmin shows different forms in dependency on user permissions. I've solved it with ModelForm's (get_form, get_fieldsets), but what to do with inlines?

```
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NewsAdminForm
    writing_form = NewsWritingForm

    inlines = (LinkInline, FileInline)
```

ModelAdmin initializes them in `ModelAdmin.__init__()` before getting request object. The only way seems to use CSS to hide them.

Answer (score 11):

You can use ModelAdmin get_inline_instances function.
Following code removes inlines from add_view:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import FooModel

class FooInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = FooModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [FooInline]

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        return obj and super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj) or []
```

Comment: I used this as well, to remove all inlines.  Then I wanted to remove some inlines, so I used `return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)[0:3]` to get the first 3 inlines. One could use other list manipulation to get different subsets.  If someone can tell me how to do this in a less hackity hack hack way I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

`ModelAdmin.__init__()` takes the classes in `ModelAdmin.inlines`, instantiates them, and stores the results in `ModelAdmin.inline_instances`. You can set `ModelAdmin.inline_instances` to an empty list after `__init__` to remove the inlines.

See line 243 of [django/contrib/admin/options.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.4/django/contrib/admin/options.py)

Comment: I've tried to set `context['inline_instances'] = []` in `render_change_form`, but it raises Validation error when saving. ( Django 1.3 ). I'll try to set `self.inline_instances = []` to empty

Comment: Hm.. I consider using css would be easier. In your variant I have to reinit Inline instances and add them to context object. Much work and copy-pasting of django source code

Comment: `render_change_form` seems like a poor choice for this type of logic. Check the user permissions in something like `change_view` and set `self.inline_instances` appropriately, and you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: this doesn't address the need to filter the inlines based on properties of the user viewing the ModelAdmin.  this __init__ doesn't have a reference to the request and therefore the request.user

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by putting the logic to set `self.inline_instances = []` in the `get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None)` method.

For example, if you wanted to show the inlines to superusers but not to anyone else:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return ()
    else:
        self.inline_instances = []
        return ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used bskinner's trick to hide inlines when adding a new object, with two adjustments: First, I had to overwrite "inlines", not "inline_instances", and second, make sure you always return self.readonly_fields, to make sure you are preserving those when they are set.

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj: 
        # edit mode... add fields here to make them read-only when editing
        return self.readonly_fields
    else:
        self.inlines = []
        return self.readonly_fields
```